# Template way of finding maximum allowable value

Tags: c++, templates, range, max

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ variable types limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966893/c-variable-types-limits)

I have a defined type that may not stay at what it is.  I want to make use of the maximum value for that type as an undefined value but don't want to use something like, INT_MAX because I might later change the type to a long or something else entirely.  I've seen a template way of doing this but now cannot find it.  How in a tempated safe way can i find the maximum allowable value for a type?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966893/c-variable-types-limits

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use:

```
std::numeric_limits<T>::max()
```

It's in the header `<limits>`. See here:

https://cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/