# signed integers overflowing to negatives: is this a compiler bug, or have I misunderstood an optimisation?

Tags: c++, g++

The following snippet of C++ code computes Fibonacci numbers.  With 32-bit integers, we overflow when `n=47` and `b` becomes negative.

```
int a=0, b=1, n=2;
do {
   a += b; int c = a; a = b; b = c;
   ++n;
} while ( b>0 and n<50 );
std::cout << "Ended at n=" << n << " b=" << b << std::endl;
```

Compiling on g++ 4.9.1 all is well; unless I use `-O2` or `-O3` in which case the loop runs until `n=50`.  Is the compiler perhaps assuming that, as `a` and `b` start out positive and only additions are applied, they must stay positive?  A look at the assembly output confirms that the condition `b>0` isn't even being checked.

Same happens for g++ 4.7.0.  So I suspect this is deliberate behaviour...?

Comment: It's expected because it's UB according to the standard, use `-fwrapv` if you want to define it. Trying to look up duplicates, but can't find a canonical answer ...

Comment: Great, many thanks.  There is some discussion e.g. http://thiemonagel.de/2010/01/signed-integer-overflow/

Comment: highest-upvoted potential dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: This code invokes undefined behavior according to [expr]/4. Therefore a compiler can deduce that since no negative value can be assigned to `b` without UB (which case the compiler doesn't consider any further), `b` can't get negative and thus that condition doesn't need to be checked.

As noted in the comments, the flag `-fwrapv` [instructs the compiler to](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html)

> […] assume that signed arithmetic overflow of addition, subtraction and
>   multiplication wraps around using twos-complement representation. This
>   flag enables some optimizations and disables others.

With it GCC should produce the same program as with optimization levels lower than O2.