# Task: describe what the following C program does?

Tags: c

this is the code (copy & pasted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char x,y,result;
    //Sample 1:
    x =  35;
    y =  85;
    result =  x + y;
    printf("Sample 1: %hi + %hi = %hi\n",x ,y, result);
    //Sample 2:
    x =  85;
    y =  85;
    result = x + y;
    printf("Sample 2: %hi + %hi = %hi\n",x ,y, result);
return 0; 
}
```

I've tried to compile it but it doesn't work. Am I stupid or is it "int" or "short" instead of char at the beginning? Once I change this it works, but I'm worried that it should work as is...
Does the program really just add x and y and show the result? That's what it does if I use short instead of char.

Thanks in advance!

E: Why the down votes? What is wrong with my post?

Comment: `but it doesn't work` - please describe what errors you get, and what actually does not work (output you get versus output you expect)

Comment: It compiles fine here. What does not work ? Does it compile ? If no, what errors do you get on which lines ? If you write "it doesn't work", the question will most likely be downvoted.

Comment: And, please include **how** you compile it - with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall` I get no errors or warnings

Comment: Just a polite reminder, your downvotes are because you are (possibly) abusing stackoverflow. It seems like 1st/year-0 University PRojects to me (or you are learning C yourself). Stackoverflow is for problems that are not common/blockers to professional people. No one is trying to be mean to you :)

Comment: When you say that something does not work, you should explain two things: (#1) what did you expect your program to do, and (#2) what did the program do instead. Also, the title of your post is a downvote magnet.

Comment: @hagubear: I don't think the OP is "possibly abusing" SO. Yes there wasn't quite as much info in the question as to what exactly wasn't understood and that is a problem. But SO is only "for professionals"? I disagree... it is a teaching/learning tool and this appears to be a very genuine and legitimate misunderstanding and quite an important point for anyone working in C to understand, professional or student. There's nothing wrong with a uni project or self learning in my opinion if there is a genuine point someone can't understand... everybody learns.

Comment: @Jimbo Google Stack Overflow. "**Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers**. It's 100% free, no registration required. Take the 2-minute tour." It is not a site for teaching and learning programming and it never was. This has been debated endlessly on Meta.

Comment: Questions with code should describe what is expected to happen, what does happen, error/exception messages and what was found during testing and debugging so far.  Anything else should expect a down or close vote.

Answer (score 4):

#### Thoughts:

For an introductory course, this is a **terrible** example. Depending on your implementation, `char` is either a signed or unsigned number. And the code will behave very differently depending on this fact.

That being said, yes, this code is basically adding two numbers and printing the result. I agree that the `%hi` is odd. That expects a `short int`. I'd personally expect either `%hhi` or just `%i`, and let integer promotion do it's thing.

#### If the numbers are unsigned chars

- `85 + 35 == 120`, which is probably less than CHAR_MAX (which is probably 255). So there's no problem and everything works fine.
- `85 + 85 == 170`, which is probably less than CHAR_MAX (which is probably 255). So there's no problem and everything works fine.

#### If the numbers are signed chars

- `85 + 35 == 120`, which is probably less than CHAR_MAX (which is probably 127). So there's no problem and everything works fine.
- `85 + 85 == 170`, which is probably **greater** than CHAR_MAX. This causes signed integer overflow, which is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the program appears to be

```
Sample 1: 35 + 85 = 120
Sample 2: 85 + 85 = -86
```

I compiled this on http://ideone.com/ and it worked fine.

The output is in fact what you would expect. The program is working! The reason you are seeing a number that you do not expect is due to the width of a `char` data type - 1 byte.

The C standard does not dictate whether `char` is signed or unsigned but assuming it is signed it can represent numbers in the range `-128` to `127` (a char is 8 bits or 1 byte). `85 + 85 = 170` which is outside of this range... the MSB of the byte becomes 1 and the number system wraps round to give you a negative number. Try reading up on [***twos compliment arithmetic***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

The arithmetic is:

```
 01010101 +
 01010101
 --------
 10101010
```

Because the data type is signed and the MSB is set, the number is now negative, in this case -86

Note: Bill Lynch's answer... he has rightly pointed out that signed overflow is UB

Comment: Signed integer overflow is actually just undefined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is

Comment: Very good point, thanks Bill. +1 to your main answer and comment :) Interesting link... learnt something