# evaluation of an expression in an if statement in c

Tags: c

suppose i write a code as:

```
int main()
{
    int i,a=2147483647;

    if((2*a)<0)
        printf("hello");
    else
    printf("world");
}
```

the output is world.
but for :

```
int main()
{
    int i,a=2147483647;
    if((a+a)<0)
        printf("hello");
    else
        printf("world");
}
```

The output is `hello`.

How is this happening? 
 And where is the value of 2*a and a+a stored in memory(what is the datatype of the memory location?)

Comment: Overflow in signed integer aritimetic is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The value of `2*a` and `a+a` may be stored in an register and nowhere in memory. See your compiler's output for further investigation.

Comment: To see the value of `a+a` put it in another *int*

Comment: It may depend on your machine, OS and compiler. Ubunto 4.8.2 with gcc 4.8.4 gives `hello` on both

Comment: This can be compiler dependent. Study the assembly language generated in the case of no specific assignment (like you are doing in the conditional expression) and compare that to the explicit assignment to an int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, etc. Its best though to always assign to a data type to avoid problems like this. Makes it easier to debug too.

Comment: Can you post the assembly of both implementations of main? Most debuggers have a way to get at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `INT_MAX` is `2147483647` (`pow(2, 31) - 1`), `2*a` and `a+a` do cause overflow, and overflow in signed integer aritimetic is *undefined behavior* in C.

Quote from [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5 Expressions:

> 5 If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the
>   result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its
>   type), the behavior is undefined.

Undefined behavior can cause *everything*. See your compiler's output to know the reason for this specific result.

To know where the value of `2*a` and `a+a` are stored, also see your compiler's output. I guess they should be stored in register, not in memory if your compiler is smart enough. Some poor compiler may store their value on the stack on the memory.

Comment: Is overflow undefined with *unsigned* integers?  Or does it have predictable behavior?

Comment: @selbie It is defined. See N1256 6.2.5 Types or [c++ - Why is unsigned integer overflow defined behavior but signed integer overflow isn't? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)

Comment: A good compiler would store it nowhere, excising the whole program since it causes UB  :D