# Does i++ invoke undefined behavior for signed types smaller than int in case of overflow?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

It seems clear that the following code invokes undefined behavior because of arithmetic overflow:

```
#include <limits.h>

int test(void) {
    int i = INT_MAX;
    i++;  /* undefined behavior */
    return i;
}
```

But what about signed types smaller than `int` such as `short` or `signed char`? (by smaller, I assume `SCHAR_MAX < INT_MAX` and `SHRT_MAX < INT_MAX` respectively).

Which of the functions below invoke undefined behavior and why?

```
signed char test2(void) {
    signed char i = SCHAR_MAX;
    i = i + 1;   /* implementation defined */
    return i;
}

signed char test3(void) {
    signed char i = SCHAR_MAX;
    i += 1;   /* undefined behavior or implementation defined? */
    return i;
}

signed char test4(void) {
    signed char i = SCHAR_MAX;
    i++;      /* undefined behavior or implementation defined? */
    return i;
}

signed char test5(void) {
    signed char i = SCHAR_MAX;
    ++i;      /* undefined behavior or implementation defined? */
    return i;
}
```

Please provide references from or quote the C Standard to support your reasoning.

Comment: A signed integer is a signed integer, no matter the underlying type and its size. However, if you in `test2` had e.g. `int j = i + 1;` then that would be well-defined because then `i` is [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to an `int`.

Comment: What made you think i++ leads to undefined behavior? I thought the behavior is well defined.

Comment: @DonghuiZhang signed integer overflow isn't "mandatory"

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is unsigned integer overflow defined behavior but signed integer overflow isn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Thank you for the link! Helpful to me. Now I see why signed integer flow is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the expression `i+1`, `i` is promoted to an `int` regardless of whether the result is assigned to an `int` or a `char` (or ignored or used in any other way). So the reason that `test2` exhibits implementation-defined behaviour is that `i+1` evaluates to an `int` using the promotion (so that part is perfectly well-defined) and then that int (which may be too big now) is converted back to `signed char`. Now converting a value that's too big is implementation-defined (as opposed to overflow which is undefined) and that's the point of `test2`.

Comment: Please pick a single language. C and C++ may differ here.

Comment: Also please focus on a single example. Prefix ++ and postfix ++ differ here.

Comment: @2501: I am interested in any differences between C and C++ for this issue. It is also **very** interesting to determine if prefix and postfix behave differently and why.

Comment: Why is the question then: does i++ invoke UB? This is entirely different than the question how the languages differ.

Comment: "invoke undefined behavior" is an unfortunate (though widespread) formulation. The behavior of a program that has an integer overflow is undefined. There's nothing to "invoke"; it simply means that the C++ language definition does not tell you what that program should do.

Comment: Note that `test2` will be undefined behaviour if `sizeof(int) == 1`.  (This is very much a corner case though...)

Comment: @MartinBonner Or all of them if SCHAR_MAX == INT_MAX.

Comment: @2501: I agree that all of them should if  `SCHAR_MAX == INT_MAX`, but I explicit said *smaller than int*.  Updated the question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 4):

It would be logical for the `+=` and similar operators to operate directly on values of the destination type, and on many implementations that is in fact what they do.  The Standard, however, requires that the operator behave as though the value of the destination undergoes any applicable standard and balancing promotions, then processes the specified operation, and then gets converted back to the destination type.

Consequently, if `s` and `u` are signed and unsigned 16-bit variables, and `int` is 32 bits, then `s*=s;` will be defined for all values of `s` [if the result exceeds 32767, it must either yield an implementation-defined value or raise an implementation-defined signal; most implementations would have to go out of their way to do anything other than two's-complement reduction].  On the other hand, `u*=u;` will only be guaranteed to wrap mod 65536 for values of `u` up to 46340; for larger values, it will invoke Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does cause and overflow and thus undefined behavior:

```
signed char i = SCHAR_MAX;
i++;
```

The operator postfix ++ does not perform integer promotions or usual arithmetic conversions<sup>1</sup>. The operator simply adds one to the value of the operand<sup>2</sup>. The operations overflows.

A clear distinction comes from the wording of the unary arithmetic operators: `+`, `-`, `~`, for which the wording clearly says that the operand is promoted<sup>3</sup>. But for the postfix `++` operator the wording doesn't say that the operator is promoted<sup>4</sup>.

Clearly the postfix ++ operator does not promote the operand.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers 2 58))
The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain
argument expressions, to the operands of the unary +, -, and ~ operators, and to both operands of the
shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators 2)
As a side effect, the
value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
added to it)

<sup>3</sup>  (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators 2)
The result of the unary + operator is the value of its (promoted) operand. The integer
promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

<sup>4</sup>  (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators 2)
The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.

Comment: @BaummitAugen the quote "If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined." does not exemplify your assertion that "the resulting type is orthogonal to the type the arithmetic is performed in [with regard to the undefined-behavior induction]".

Comment: @user694733 Sequence points have nothing to do with size of evaluation. You 'argument' is self contradictory because the last sizeof evaluation does in fact yield the size of the operand after it is promoted.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Usual arithmetic promotions apply only when specified, otherwise they don't apply. Postfix ++ doesn't specify that they apply, thus they don't. Even if you ignore the non-normative footnote and the practical example, there are still the last two normative quotes from the standard (which you forgot to address) which show that some unary operands promote the operand and other don't.

Comment: @2501 I believe you are wrong. As user694733 pointed out, conversions in postfix and prefix increment/decrement are referred to *6.5.16.2 Compound assignment*, which states: *3
A compound assignment of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to the simple assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2)[...]*. Thus, the values *are* promoted.

Comment: @EOF the equivalence ignores possibilities of undefined behavior that occur orthogonally to the behavioral equivalence. Because the increment-result does not fit into a `char`, behavior is undefined. The argument that the expression is equivalent to another expression, which does not involve undefined behavior, is valid - but is irrelevant to the question of whether or not the expression has defined behavior or not.

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not really believe that, but please provide a counter-argument to my view!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: It's explicitly *equivalent*. If you want to weaken the meaning of "equivalent", you're welcome to all the madness that ensures.

Comment: @EOF You're confusing compound assignments i+=1, with unary postfix and prefix increment ++ . Those are completely different operators. The latter two operators are not mentioned anywhere  in 6.5.16.

Comment: @2501 I'm not confusing anything here. The standard *explicitly* refers to the sections on additive operators and compound assignment in the *normative sections* on prefix and postfix increment and decrement.

Comment: @EOF No it doesn't. You haven't provided a single quote from the standard that would prove your claim. The first comment you posted disproves itself: *conversions in postfix and prefix increment/decrement are referred to 6.5.16.2 Compound assignment, which states: 3 A compound assignment of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to the simple assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2)[...]. Thus, the values are promoted. – EOF 7 hours ago* There are no mentions of postfix operators in that standard quote.

Comment: @2501: Unless the Standard defines a special meaning for the phrase "1 of the appropriate type is added to it", I don't see any reasonable basis for a compiler writer assuming that it should not compute the sum in the same manner as the other ways the Standard defines for adding 1 to something (i.e. `lvalue=lvalue+1;` and `lvalue+=1;`).

Comment: @supercat I see at least two good reasons which are posted in the answer. Those being the footnote and the rules for operators. Would the standard really misdirect the reader with the footnote, and then forget to apply a rule for the postfitx operator. I don't think so.

Comment: @2501 The footnote does *not* say the operand to the increment operators are not promoted, it refers to the *usual arithmetic conversions* which apply to the additive operators and the compound assignment operators, which are *explicitly* referred on the topic of conversions by the section on increment/decrement operators.