# Why aren't both of these simple loops infinite?

Tags: c++, for-loop

The answer to this will probably not benefit me in any way professionally, but I'm keen to know: why aren't these two simple C++ loops both infinite?

Loop 1 (infinite)

```
constexpr unsigned short max = USHRT_MAX;
for (signed short ss = 0; ss < max; ++ss);
```

Loop 2 (not infinite)

```
constexpr unsigned int max = UINT_MAX;
for (signed int si = 0; si < max; ++si);
```

Output for loop one shows that ss increments to `SHRT_MAX`, then to -`SHRT_MAX` - 1, then to -1 (or `USHRT_MAX`), and repeats that loop infinitely.

Output for loop two shows that si increments to `INT_MAX`, then to -`INT_MAX - 1`, then to -1 (or `UINT_MAX`), and then stops.

Can someone supply the missing information I need about how these integer types work, be it implicit conversion, implementation oddities, etc?

Comment: Both loops have undefined behavior because of signed integer overflow (if you are not using C++20).

Comment: i would say that is UB since arithmetic overflow is UB

Comment: Both loops give undefined behavior (they overflow a signed integer type), so might manifest as an infinite loop or non-infinite, or crash or something else.

Comment: Because `short max` is converted to `int` before the comparison, while `int si` is converted to `unsigned` before comparison. See for example [conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Any reason why the undefined behaviors are different depending on the integer types used? It seems so arbitrary. @dxiv if that were true, why would the output for si show negative numbers?

Comment: @grahfoster Undefined is undefined. You can get any result. The same loop with the same variable types may even act differently in different places of your program because, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @grahfoster That was referring to the `si < max` comparison step, only.

Comment: @TedLyngmo but the results are consistent across executions. Or are you saying you can get any result consistently depending on any changed component of the loop?

Comment: @TedLyngmo afaik signed integer is still UB in C++20. The only thing that changed is that signed integers are now required to be encoded in two's complement, but overflow is still undefined.

Comment: @grahfoster I'm saying that the program may not even start - or start and go on removing files on your disk.

Comment: @bolov Ok, I'm not 100% sure. I either read about that the behavior became defined in C++20 or I dreamt about it because it would feel _right_ :-) Edit: It seems you are correct: "_the subsequent revision is to maintain undefined behavior when signed integer overflow occurs, instead of defining wrapping behavior._"

Comment: @bolov Assuming two's complement and overflow aside, I believe OP's question is essentially why `(short)-1 < USHRT_MAX` while `(int)-1 == UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @bolov I found it - it was in the first revision of the proposal. They changed it back to undefined afterwards. Darn.

Comment: @grahfoster *but the results are consistent across executions* -- Change compiler options and maybe the results will be different.  If your code has undefined behavior, it becomes a moot point of what *that* particular rendition of the program is doing.  A change in compiler settings and rebuilding the application could have a totally different result.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I'd suggest `for (signed short ss = 0; ss < max; ++ss);` is not UB with 16-bit short, 32-bit `int`.  There is no _arithmetic overflow_, just conversion problems of `int` into `short`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `++` is not subject to integer promotions like simple unary and binary operators are.  So it operates at the type of the lvalue being incremented, and all the undefined behavior of signed overflow applies.

Comment: @dxiv yes, precisely. I think I understand how type promotions cause those comparisons to evaluate the way they do now—thanks!

Comment: Please don't roll back edits that improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

As they said this is undefined behavior, but in your case it might be that comparison values are converted to `int` thus second one is infinite, since it does not co to `USHRT_MAX` (`65535`) instead it goes to `SHORT_MAX` and overflows to negative values. See this:

5/9: (Expressions)

> Many binary operators that expect
> operands of arithmetic or enumeration
> type cause conversions and yield
> result types in a similar way. The
> purpose is to yield a common type,
> which is also the type of the result.
> This pattern is called the usual
> arithmetic conversions, which are
> defined as follows:

> - If either
>   operand is of type long double, the
>   other shall be converted to long
>   double.

> - Otherwise, if either operand
>   is double, the other shall be
>   converted to double.

> - Otherwise, if
>   either operand is float, the other
>   shall be converted to float.

> - Otherwise, the integral promotions
>   (4.5) shall be performed on both
>   operands.54)

> - Then, if either operand
>   is unsigned long the other shall be
>   converted to unsigned long.

> - Otherwise, if one operand is a long
>   int and the other unsigned int, then
>   if a long int can represent all the
>   values of an unsigned int, the
>   unsigned int shall be converted to a
>   long int; otherwise both operands
>   shall be converted to unsigned long
>   int.

> - Otherwise, if either operand is
>   long, the other shall be converted to
>   long.

> - Otherwise, if either operand
>   is unsigned, the other shall be
>   converted to unsigned.

4.7/2: (Integral conversions)

> If the destination type is unsigned,
> the resulting value is the least
> unsigned integer congruent to the
> source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is
> the number of bits used to represent
> the unsigned type). [Note: In a two’s
> complement representation, this
> conversion is conceptual and there is
> no change in the bit pattern (if there
> is no truncation). ]

Comment: Got here already with @dxiv's comments but thank you for putting it all in once place!

Comment: @grahfoster I saw his comments after I did wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [Does i++ invoke undefined behavior for signed types smaller than int in case of overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344147/2410359) for a needed correction to the next paragraph.

Its UB

<strike>`signed short ss = 0; ss < max; ++ss)` problem is that `++ss` is like `ss = ss+ 1` and that is *implementation defined behavior* in the assignment when `SHRT_MAX < INT_MAX`. `ss+1` is well defined, but the assignment is at issue.   Whatever the implementation, `ss` will never reach `USHRT_MAX`.  When `SHRT_MAX < USHRT_MAX`, the loop is infinite.</strike>

---

`signed int si = 0; si < max; ++si` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as `++ss` incurs signed integer overflow (which is UB) before reaching the limit of `ss < max`.
A common UB of `++si` when `si == INT_MAX` is to wrap, making `si == INT_MIN`.  Eventually `si == -1` and `si < max;` is like `(unsigned)-1 < max` which is false, stopping the loop.

> Why aren't both of these simple loops infinite?

The 2nd loop is *undefined*.  For to certainly behave would require *defined behavior*.

Had `short` had the same size as `int`, both would be UB - yet still would not be required to behave the same.

---

Recommend:

```
constexpr unsigned short max = USHRT_MAX;
//   vv
for (unsigned short ss = 0; ss < max; ++ss);
```

and

```
constexpr unsigned int max = UINT_MAX;
//   vv
for (unsigned int si = 0; si < max; ++si);
```

Comment: "A common UB of ++si when si == INT_MAX is to wrap, making si == INT_MIN. Eventually si == -1 and si < max; is like (unsigned)-1 < max which is false, stopping the loop."
This line answered the question, thank you very much.

Comment: @grahfoster Hmmmm, Might not be so, See [@ChrisDodd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043910/why-arent-both-of-these-simple-loops-infinite?noredirect=1#comment111485968_63043910)