# Caesar cipher in C - encryption and decryption

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

I made this program and seems that doesn't work can you tell me why? I spent like 3 hours just figuring out why it's not working but I have no clue. I'm wondering if it's not something with shift but I'm not sure. That's my first program I'm making so sorry about some basic mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   char message[100];
   int shift;
   int i;
   int choice;

   printf("Enter operation with message\n");
   printf("encrypt - 1\n");
   printf("decrypt - 2\n");
   scanf("%d", &choice);

   switch(choice)
   {
      case 1:
      {
         printf("Enter message to encrypt\n");
         scanf("%d", &message);

         printf("Enter shift\n");
         scanf("%d", &shift);

         for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++)
         {
            message[i] = message[i] + shift;
            if (message[i] > 'z')
               message[i] = message[i] - 26;
         }
         printf("Encrypted message: %s\n", message);
         break;
      }
      case 2: 
      {
         printf("Enter message to decrypt\n");
         scanf("%d", &message);

         printf("Enter shift\n");
         scanf("%d", &shift);

         for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++)
         {
            message[i] = message[i] - shift;
            if (message[i] > 'z')
               message[i] = message[i] - 26;
         }
         printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", message);
         break;
      }
   }

   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here a screen of output:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: *"seems that doesn't work can you tell me why?"* We can't, because you haven't told us **how** it doesn't work. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Cases in switch statement must be enclosed in curly braces `{}` like `case 1 { ... }`

Comment: One ' basic mistake' is trying to develop programs without knowing how to use your debugger:(

Comment: @campovski that is not the case - braces are optional. the end of the case is defined by the `break` or closing brace of the `switch`

Comment: If I compile this code I get many warnings e.g.: wrong format specifier for `scanf()`: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]`, etc. You should take care of them! This line will miserably fail: `scanf("%d", &message);`! Further there are logical errors about your decryption which is mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: Three situations where this code will not work: 1) upper case letters, 2) `shift < 0`, 3) `shift > 26`

Comment: Just a quick look - on the decrypt - try this move the "- shift" line to after the check for lower case?

Comment: Hmm.. it seems like you have made another 'basic error' - not heeding the warnings from your compiler.  Using the wrong format specifier for the 'message' string is a very basic error that your compiler would have warned of, as noted by @AndreKampling.  Also note that scanf() returns a value that you should check.

Comment: `char message[100]; ... scanf("%d", &message);`?!?!?  As others have noted, pay attention to your warnings, and check return values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always pay attention to the compiler warnings. If I compile your code I get the following warnings (and some more):

> ```
> ../main.c:21:10: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
>           scanf("%d", &message);
>           ^
> ../main.c:38:10: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
>           scanf("%d", &message);
>           ^
> ```

There are 2 main problems:

**1. Wrong format specifier with [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/scanf):**

Read about the different format specifier [here on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/scanf).
In you code you're using:

```
char message[100];
scanf("%d", &message);
```

but instead of `%d` which is used for `int` it should be `%s` for C-strings (`char*`). Better use `%99s` to avoid a [string format vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c). Further it should be just `message` without the ampersand (`&`) because [the array name will decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to a `char*` but `&message` will be a pointer to an array: `char (*)[100]`. This would result in a warning because `%s` expects `char*`.

```
char message[100];
if (1 != scanf("%99s", message)) /* buffer size - 1 */
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Moreover `scanf()` returns the number of successful read elements. I recommend always check the return values that indicate errors.

**2. Logical error in decryption:**

Instead of checking `message[i] > 'z'` it must be `message[i] < 'a'` as you're subtracting the `shift` value. Further add 26 instead of subtracting it in that case.

```
for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
   message[i] = message[i] - shift;
   if (message[i] < 'a')
      message[i] = message[i] + 26;
}
```

---

**Edit #1:**

There is also another logical problem about the message you type in. Your code will only work for messages that consists of lower letters. You can extend that to work with upper letters to.

Further your buffer will may hold `signed char`s<sup>1</sup> as it is declared as `char message[100];`, that means if the calculation: `message[i] = message[i] + shift;` [overflows the bahaviour is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is). That would happen for example if you use character `z` (decimal 122 in [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/)) and a `shift` of 6 which will lead to 128 but a `signed char` can hold at most 127.

---

<sup>1</sup> I write *"may hold `signed char`s"* because the C standard leaves it up to the implementation to [define wether a `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default), but for GCC and MSVC a `char` will be a `signed char` by default.

Comment: @popcorn: I've added some more considerations to my answer. Please have a look at them.

Comment: I checked that out, thanks so much, now my code works pretty good, thank you so much! :-) I'm gonna try to add Vigenere cipher, so if i get some troubles i will show here :) :p