# Print an empty line every other line when reading from file

Tags: c

In my .txt file I have follow data.

Name: name
Score: 0.00%
Name: name
Score: 0.00%
Name: name
Score:6.67%

and I tried using this code

```
    if (userAnswer1 == 3){
        printf("Test History\n\n");
        FILE * fPointer;
        fPointer = fopen("history.txt", "r");
        char singleLine[50];
        while(!feof(fPointer)) {
            fgets(singleLine, 50, fPointer);
            puts(singleLine);
            int i;
            for(i=0; i>=0; i++){
                if(i%2==0){
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fPointer);
    }
```

to get this output:

Name: name
Score: 0.00%

Name: name
Score: 0.00%

Name: name
Score: 6.67%

Instead of that I got below output.

Test History

Name: name

Score: 0.00%

Name: name

Score: 0.00%

Name: name

Score: 6.67%

Score: 6.67%

Comment: This is impossible to reproduce. There is no `andre` anywhere. Please create [mcve].

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: 'for(i=0; i>=0; i++)' ??  is that condition not always true, (at least until wrap)?

Comment: Oh.. it's like for(;;), but with more typing:)

Comment: @MartinJames Even if it wraps, it's [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195715/5958455).

Comment: May be unrelated to your question, but `fopen` can fail. You need to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    printf("Test History\n\n");

    FILE *pToFile = fopen("history.txt", "r");

    char input[50];
    int i=0;
    while(fgets(input, 50, pToFile)){
        printf("%s", input);
        i++;
        if(i%2==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(pToFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things: The [`puts`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) function writes a newline; And the [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) functions may include the newline in the buffer.

That means when you print `singleLine` first there is a newline (because `fgets` put it there), then `puts` writes its own newline.

Either remove the newline that `fgets` writes into the buffer, or don't use `puts`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!feof(fPointer)){
    fgets(singleLine, 50, fPointer);
    puts(singleLine);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i>=0; i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

There are a few things to note:

1. [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) reads until a newline, and **includes it** to the buffer. So on the following [`puts()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) call, you've already output a newline after that, and `puts()` even adds a newline on its own.
2. Consider this code:

   ```
   int i;
   for(i=0; i>=0; i++){
       if(i%2==0){
           printf("\n");
       }
       break;
   }
   ```

   You're actually printing one newline, then break the loop. So it makes no difference from a plain

   ```
   printf("\n");
   ```

Counting both things above, you're actually printing 3 newlines every `while` loop: One is what `fgets()` writes to the buffer, one from `puts()`, one manually.

To fix them, you need to do two jobs:

1. Strip the newline from whatever `fgets()` gives you:

   ```
   singleLine[strlen(singleLine) - 1] = '\0';
   ```
2. Make the loop work better:

   ```
   int i = 0; // Must initialize!
   while (condition) {
       other_statements;

       i++;
       if (i%2==0) {
           printf("\n");
       }
       // Do nothing if 'i' is odd
   }
   ```
3. Stop using `while (!feof())`. Check the return value of `fgets` instead:

   ```
   char *ret = fgets( ... );
   if (ret == NULL)
       break;
   ```

Comment: Ok, so i tried this, but it will not print anything now except empty lines.
I guess
singleLine[strlen(singleLine) - 1] = '\0';
seem to remove it all

Comment: So i came a little closer to a solution,
            int i=0;  
            while(!feof(fPointer)){    
            fgets(singleLine, 50, fPointer);  
            printf("%s", singleLine);  
                i++;  
                    if(i%2==0){  
                        printf("\n");  
                    }  
this seem to work except that it prints out the last score again;  
"Score: 6.67%"

Comment: @andre2012 Don't use `while(!feof())`. Check the return value of `fgets` instead.

Comment: thanks for the help, didnt really understand but checket tutorial on youtube and got it right, will post code in a reply.

Comment: @ander2012 Which part don't you understand?

Comment: kinda new to programming, so barely anything with checking return value of fgets, i know it can return NULL or something else. I guess that if it returns NULL it is supposed to stop checking in the file

Answer (score -2):

the trouble is with your logic - you have the 'if' inside the 'while' so it loops and counts on each 'while' (line from your file).

I'm not c expert, so no code, but it seems you get the commands.  The logic I would use is to look a the text in the line and add the '\n' from that.

i.e.

```
if singleline (contains - however you do that in c) "%"
```

add the \n