# int_fast_ types and value overflow

Tags: c

If I understand well, `int_fast_n_t` types are guaranteed to be at least `n` bits long. Depending on the compiler and the architecture of the computer these types can also be defined on more than `n` bits. For instance, a `int_fast_8_t` could be interpreted as a 32 bits `int`.

Is there some kind of mechanism which enforces that the value of an `int_fast_n_t` never overflow even if the true type is defined on more than `n` bits?

Consider the following code for example:

```
int main(){
    int_fast8_t a = 64;
    a *= 2; // -128
    return 0;
}
```

I do not want `a` to be greater than `127`. If `a` is interpreted as a "regular" `int` (32 bits), is it possible that `a` exceed `127` and be not equal to `-128`?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: No. You could cast the result to something which really is 8 bits, though.

Comment: Is `int_fast8_t` really 32 bits? The name suggest 8 bit so it can only hold 127 as positive number. Casting to `(char)` should do the trick! Typically `char` is only 8 bits.

Comment: @sg7: Depends on the platform. On my machine uint_fast16/32_t are 64 bits, though uint_fast8_t is 8.

Comment: @sg7 it means "A type which is at least 8 bits and is the fastest for holding 8-bit data". It could be any size 8 or greater, and it has the properties of its actual size (not the properties of an 8-bit integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int_fast8_t a = 64;
a *= 2;
```

> If a is interpreted as a "regular" int (32 bits), is it possible that a exceed 127 and be not equal to -128?

Yes.  It very likely `a * 2` will save in `a` as 128.  I would expect this on all processors unless the processor was an 8-bit one.

> Is there some kind of mechanism which enforces that the value of an `int_fast_n_t` never overflow ?

No.  Signed integer overflow is still possible as well as values outside the [-128...127] range.

> I do not want a to be greater than 127

Use `int8_t`.  The value save will never exceed 127, yet code still has *implementation defined behavior* in setting a 128 to an `int8_t`.  This often results in -128 (values wrap mod 256), yet other values are possible (this is uncommon).

```
int8_t a = 64;
a *= 2;
```

---

If assignment to `int8_t` is not available or has unexpected *implementation defined behavior*, code could force the wrapping itself:

```
int_fast8_t a = foo();  // a takes on some value
a %= 256; 
if (a < -128) a += 256;
else if (a > 127) a -= 256;
```

Comment: int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t are not guaranteed to be defined on every platform?

Comment: @Papipone That is true, yet OP does not appear to be on such an esoteric machine.  If we venture to non-8-bit `char`, we might as well consider _sign magnitude_ and _one's complement_, and traps.  Likely beyond OP''s need.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible for the result to exceed 127. `int_fast8_t` (and `uint_fast8_t` and all the rest) set an explicit minimum size for the value, but it could be larger, and the compiler will not prevent it from exceeding the stated 8 bit bounds (it behaves exactly like the larger type it represents, the "8ness" of it isn't relevant at runtime), only guarantee it can definitely represent all values in said 8 bit range.

If you need it to explicitly truncate/wrap to 8 bit values, either use (or cast to) `int8_t` to restrict the representable range (though [overflow wouldn't be defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195715/364696)), or explicitly use masks to perform the same work yourself when needed.

Comment: Note there is no _overflow_ involved here, just _conversion_.

Comment: Upvoted this because I didnt know about uint_fast8_t :) Thank you for the nice explanation as well~

Answer (score 1):

Nope. All the fast types really are are typedefs. For example, stdint.h on my machine includes

```
/* Fast types.  */

/* Signed.  */
typedef signed char     int_fast8_t;
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long int        int_fast16_t;
typedef long int        int_fast32_t;
typedef long int        int_fast64_t;
#else
typedef int         int_fast16_t;
typedef int         int_fast32_t;
__extension__
typedef long long int       int_fast64_t;
#endif

/* Unsigned.  */
typedef unsigned char       uint_fast8_t;
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef unsigned long int   uint_fast16_t;
typedef unsigned long int   uint_fast32_t;
typedef unsigned long int   uint_fast64_t;
#else
typedef unsigned int        uint_fast16_t;
typedef unsigned int        uint_fast32_t;
__extension__
typedef unsigned long long int  uint_fast64_t;
#endif
```

The closest you can come without a significant performance penalty is probably casting the result to an 8-bit type.

Answer (score 1):

Just use unsigned char if you want to manipulate 8 bits (unsigned char is one byte long) you will work on  0 to 0xFF (255) unsigned range

Comment: unsigned char (or char for that matter) is only 8 bits if CHAR_BIT == 8. There is no type in C which is guaranteed to exist and be 8-bits.

Comment: Hi @nemequ, are you sure? I have never heard of any situation where char size differs from 8 bits.

Comment: Yes. They're very rare in anything even remotely modern (4 and 6 bits was common up to ~ 1970), but AFAIK some specialized processors do still use something other than 8 bits. More importantly, the C standard does not require 8 bits, otherwise why include a CHAR_BIT macro?

Answer (score 1):

From the C(99) [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1p1):

> The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N
>   , no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t
>   denotes a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

So use `int8_t` to guarantee 8 bit int.

A compliant C99/C11 compiler on a POSIX platform must have `int8_t`.

Comment: "`int8_t` to guarantee 8 bit int" is true yet `int8_t b = 128;` is not specified to store -128.  Although that is very common.

Comment: @chux Thank you for the comment. My understanding is that  `int8_t` has to have two’s complement representation as per standard. And the following source: `https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdint.h` specifies the range as `<-128,127>`

Comment: The issue is not  about  `int8_t`.  The concern is _conversion_ of a value, like 128, that is outside the target range [-128...127] - which is _implementation defined behavior_.  Even with `int8_t` specified as you say, a complier _could_ assign 127 (or other values) to `int8_t c`.  I doubt such compilers practically exist except for hostile ones, that are designed to stress test code.

Comment: `int8_t` is optional in C99/C11; does POSIX specify that it must exist? Also, the representation of signed integers is not defined; two's complement is pretty universal on modern CPUs, but not technically required.

Comment: @nemequ `int8_t is optional in C99/C11;` TRUE. However, POSIX requires `int8_t` to be defined, source: https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/7posix/stdint.h/

Comment: Hmmm, strange POSIX makes `(u)int64_t` optional, yet  `(u)int8,16,32_t`, `uint_least8,16,32,64_t`, `uint_least8,16,32,64_t` required.