# Information lost with type conversion in C

Tags: c, compilation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int x = 128;
    char y = x;
    int z = y;
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

i don't understand why this program prints -128.
i have tried to convert 128 in binary base but i'm still confused on how the C compiler convert int to char and char to int.

**Note : in my machine sizeof(char) = 1 and sizeof(int) = 4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a `char` is signed and 8 bits, its range is -128 to 127 which means the value 128 is out of range for a `char`.  So the value is converted in a implementation-defined manner.  In the case of gcc, the result is reduced modulo 2<sup>8</sup> to become in range.

What this basically means is that the low-order byte of the `int` value 128 is assigned to the `char` variable.  128 in hex as 32-bit is 0x00000080, so 0x80 is assigned to `y`.  Assuming 2's compliment representation, this represents the value -128.  When this value is then assigned to `z`, which is an `int`, that value *can* be represented in an `int`, so that's what gets assigned to it, and its representation is 0xffffff80.

Answer (score 1):

C standard [does not specify whether char is signed or unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). In fact, assigning a char type a value outside of the basic execution character set is implementation defined. You can probably use the macros in [`<limits.h>`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) to verify.

I suspect on your system `char` is signed, which makes the max value 127. [Signed interger overflow is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is). So no guarantess on the output. In this case, it looks like it wraps around.