# times() syscall. Overflowed return value

Tags: c, linux

Which value will be returned if possible clock_t (aka signed long) range will be overflowed?

Let's assume that I use kernel 2.6 version and arch is x86 (32 bits).
sizeof(signed long) = 4 bytes.
Max value = 2147483647.

According to man page - [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html), syscall *times()* returns the number of clock ticks that have elapsed since an arbitrary point in the past.

In *"Notes"* section mentioned following: *"On Linux, the "arbitrary point in the past" from which the return value of times() is measured has varied across kernel versions. Since Linux 2.6, this point is (2^32/HZ) - 300 seconds before system boot time"*.

So, I don't understand what value in decimal representation will be start point (suppose HZ = 100). And what return value will be after overflowing.

Comment: What I understand is that there is an overflow just some minutes after boot time in Linux>2.6, I suppose this to maximize the usable window, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot yet comment I hope this answer is of some use.. according to this [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html)

> times() returns the number of clock ticks that have elapsed since an
>          arbitrary point in the past.  The return value may overflow the
>          possible range of type clock_t.  On error, (clock_t) -1 is returned,
>          and errno is set appropriately.

so it can overflow, yes, and when it does it will go from **+2,147,483,647** to **−2,147,483,647** if the return is an ***unsigned long*** and continue to tick in positive direction. However ***signed integers*** are undefined after overflow, this is due to compilers handling them differently for optimization, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is).

If my assumption is correct it can overflow multiple times meaning your value could be invalid after overflow if ***unsigned*** or the value will be undefined ***(random)*** if ***signed***.

Comment: As far, as I know, overflowing of signed types in C is unspecified. So, I think that this case is handled by corresponded kernel handler.

Comment: It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, sorry I amended the answer.