# Why is signed overflow UB in C and C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I am trying to understand the rational behind defining a signed overflow in C and C++ as undefined behavior. Presumably, this is to allow optimizations not otherwise possible. It is not clear to me, however, what those optimizations are.

I know that there is a C++20 [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html) that would make signed integers in C++ more defined. At the time of this writing, however, this proposal also leaves a signed integer overflow as undefined.

Comment: AFAIK, signed overflow differs in different CPUs, so it's left undefined. Anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is

Comment: [How undefined signed overflow enables optimizations in GCC](https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-undefined-signed-overflow-enables.html).

Comment: The author of said proposal gave a [CppCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhUxIVf1qok) that covered this as far as I remember.

Comment: @NikosC. no that's not it. If you read the proposal, it seeks to define signed integers as 2's complement, and was accepted. Still, despite defining signed integers as 2's complement, overflows are still not defined.

Comment: @Cornstalks if you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.