# Why does the product of 2147453647*2147453647 show 1 and -2147453648*-2147453648 shows 0 in the below C++ program?

Tags: c++, int, range

I have declared two int variables: `n1=2147483647` (the maximum value for my compiler), and `n2=-2147453648` (the minimum value). The results of `n1*n1` and `n2*n2` are surprisingly 1 and 0.

Why these values? If it is related to the range of the data type, then could it not be any value, or the largest value an int can hold?

```
int main()
{
    int n1 = 2147483647;
    cout << "Product is : " << n1 * n1 << endl;

    int n2 = -2147483648;
    cout << "Product is : " << n2 * n2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Overflow, hence, UB.

Comment: "*2147483647 [...] which is the maximum value of a int data type*" - not necessarily. `int` isn't guaranteed to be 32 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)).

Now, if you're wondering how these specific values arise in your particular environment, they're quite simply the 32 least-significant bits (LSB) of the result:

- `2147483647*2147483647` equals `0x3fffffff00000001`, the 32 LSB of which is `0x00000001`;
- `-2147483648*-2147483648` equals `0x4000000000000000`, the 32 LSB of which is `0x00000000`.