# Why does gcc not add tmin + tmin correctly?

Tags: c, gcc, twos-complement

I've been playing around with bitwise operations and two's complement, when I discovered this oddity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int tmin = 0x80000000;
    printf("tmin + tmin: 0x%x\n", tmin + tmin);
    printf("!(tmin + tmin): 0x%x\n", !(tmin + tmin));
}
```

The code above results in the following output

```
tmin + tmin: 0x0
!(tmin + tmin): 0x0
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You're overflowing, so it causes undefined behavior. Use `unsigned int`.

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the second `printf` line.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm aware of overflow, I'm just confused because the output of the first printf seems to suggest that tmin + tmin is 0, but apparently it is not?

Comment: @DonThousand: The program has undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: The C standard does not say there is one specific result of an overflow in the `int` type. It says, anytime there is an `int` overflow, the C implementation can do anything it wants, and it can be different each time. As others have indicated but not explained, this is called undefined behavior, meaning the C standard does not impose any requirements at all. In the cases you ask about, the C compiler may simply be doing what is “easiest” for it. For example, the compiler could take an entire expression containing overflow and reduce it to 0, regardless of what else it contains.

Comment: Or it could remove the expression evaluation completely and let whatever happens to be in a processor register at that point be the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x80000000` in binary is

```
0b10000000000000000000000000000000
```

When you add two `0x80000000`s together,

```
    |<-          32bits          ->|
  0b10000000000000000000000000000000
+ 0b10000000000000000000000000000000
------------------------------------
 0b100000000000000000000000000000000
    |<-          32bits          ->|
```

However, `int` on your machine seem to have 32 bits, so only the lower 32 bits are preserved, which means the `1` in your result is silently discarded. This is called an [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Also note that in C, signed (as opposed to unsigned, i.e. `unsigned int`) integer overflow is actually [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is), which is why `!(tmin + tmin)` gives `0x0` instead of `0x1`. See [this blog post](https://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/) for an example where a variable is both true and false due to another undefined behavior, i.e. uninitialized variable.

Comment: This doesn't explain the second case.

Comment: I think I figured out my point of confusion now. If I cast the sum of tmin + tmin to an int, and then call !sum, then it will return 1 as expected.

Comment: @DonThousand "If I cast the sum of tmin + tmin to an int, and then call !sum, then it will return 1 as expected." --> You are still missing the point. The result is not _expected_, but _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @JL2210 It does, as undefined behavior can explain anything. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @DonThousand In case you don't know what is being hinted at by "undefined behavior" it's basically that corner of the specification where they didn't demand a particular outcome.  So, if you have an operation that falls into undefined behavior; even if the answer _should_ be zero according to the laws of mathematics, the answer you get _might_ be zero, or one, or a million, random, or any other number you can think of, as it's subject to the computer it's running on, and whatever implementation is taking hold at the moment.  "Undefined behavior" == "all bets are off, logic does not apply".

Comment: @EdwinBuck Yes I understand. It was just an observation.

Comment: @DonThousand I'm glad you do.  Sorry if I explained it unnecessarily.