# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when access large heap array

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

we know Segmentation fault (core dumped) is caused by illegal memory access.But i don't think it's the reason for my program.
run the following c code on linux, when the variable l=20,it works, but when l=50, i got Segmentation fault (core dumped). my laptop is ubuntu18.04, 8core,16G MEMORY.

```
//
// Created by sakura on 2020/4/11.
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void *emalloc(size_t n);
int main(){
    printf("begin alloc...\n");
    char* rv;
    int l=50;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        rv=emalloc(1024*1024*100);
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("finish alloc...\n");

    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<1024*1024*100;j++){
             int a = rand();
            rv[i*1024*1024*100+j]=(a%128);
        }
    }
    printf("finish access...\n");
    sleep(300);
    return 0;
}

void fatal(char *s1,char *s2,int n){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s, %s\n",s1,s2);
    exit(n);
}

void *emalloc(size_t n){
    void *rv;
    if((rv=malloc(n))==NULL){
        fatal("out of memory","",1);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: With `for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        rv=emalloc(1024*1024*100); ... }`, does not code   lose access to the prior allocations?

Comment: good question. the point rv should only be available to 100MB memory area. buf actually it can access 100MB*20 memory area. don't know why.

Comment: I suspect "buf actually it can access 100MB*20 memory area" is an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: when l=20, use `ps -u` i can see the RSS is 2G

Comment: Yes code _using_ 2G, but has loss [_access_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151959/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-access-large-heap-array?noredirect=1#comment108184665_61151959) to 100MB*19 of that due to the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151959/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-access-large-heap-array?noredirect=1#comment108183735_61151959).

Comment: i think the reason why i can access is the memory allocted is consecutive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got integer overflow when using `i = 50` at this line:

```c
rv[i*1024*1024*100+j]=(a%128);
```

This leads to undefined behavior (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)).

The value of `50*1024*1024*100` is equal to `5242880000`, but the maximum value for the variable of `int` type (see `INT_MAX` constant in the [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)) is `2147483647`.

I suggest you consider using a different data type for `i` variable, for example, `size_t`.