# Problem with consteval and multiplying magic numbers. c++

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, consteval

Alright, so I'm trying to make a function that will hash a string.

```cpp
consteval int hash_string(const char* str)
{
    constexpr int magic_number = 13371337;
    
    int num1 = 1337;
    int num2 = 7331;
    
    //do stuffz here//
    
    return num1 + num2 * magic_number; //error
    return num1 + num2;                //okay :D
}
```

I'm assuming that it's due to an integer overflow and that the compiler is unable to solve for it. But it's part of the algorithm, I don't care about that.

I'm expecting that consteval will solve the function because it's all compile time stuff.

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. Compile-time evaluation doesn't do undefined behavior. Does the outcome change if you switch all your integers to `unsigned`?

Comment: If you want to be a bit more in control, use `std::uint64_t` instead of `int`

Comment: Also for consteval consider using `const std::string_view` instead of `const char*` (so you can avoid pointer arithmetic)

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: Integer overflow is undefined behaviour. This means the program is legally allowed to format your hard drive, eat your lunch, and steal your girlfriend. If you want any of that to be "a part of the algorithm", go ahead and use an algorithm that can result in integer overflow. If not, *use unsigned types*. Unsigned arithmetic doesn't overflow, it wraps around.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Don't be so dramatic about undefined behavior. It is not allowed to do anything. But the side effects are unpredictable but will be limited to things happening on your computer (which can be bad enough) ;)

Comment: *But it's part of the algorithm, I don't care about that.* -- That's not how you approach implementing an algorithm in C++ code (or frankly, any language).  You must be aware of the constraints placed on the language you will be using and adjust the code accordingly.  This goes for your algorithm and many other types of algorithms that work "on paper", but need adjustment in the actual implementation.

Comment: @PepijnKramer thanks for the advice! wasn't sure if that compiled to a constexpr as well.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I get the error `[C2131] expression did not evaluate to a constant`, which in my case wasn't very clear if this had to do with the overflow.

Comment: Sure, see cppreference on [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). Specialy its [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view). From C++20 even std::string is constexpr.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes it does work! at the end I just statically cast it to an int. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to compile that code with `-fwrapv`, which to my understanding make signed integer overflow defined. But Clang still refused the code, which surprised me a bit.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI That's really interesting, wonder why an integer overflow is considered undefined opposed to unsigned overflow.

I've always thought unsigned is purely the unsigned version of an integer.

Comment: @Bard: this is for hardware historical reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65983221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it's part of the algorithm, I don't care about that.

But you should care about it, because C++ doesn't allow it. Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. And during constant evaluation, if you provoke undefined behavior, your program is ill-formed.

Hence the compile error.

If your algorithm relies on something whose results are not defined, your algorithm needs to be changed.