# Why can't you use bitwise & with numba and uint64?

Tags: python, numba

I have the following MWE:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(nb.uint64(nb.uint64))
def popcount(x): 
      b=0
      while(x > 0):
          x &= x - 1   
          b+=1
      return b


print(popcount(43))
```

It fails with:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function iand>) found for signature:
 
 >>> iand(float64, float64)
 
There are 8 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 4 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'iand': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
    With argument(s): '(float64, float64)':
   No match.
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Operator Overload in function 'iand': File: unknown: Line unknown.
    With argument(s): '(float64, float64)':
   No match for registered cases:
    * (bool, bool) -> bool
    * (int64, int64) -> int64
    * (int64, uint64) -> int64
    * (uint64, int64) -> int64
    * (uint64, uint64) -> uint64
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'gen_operator_impl.<locals>._ol_set_operator': File: numba/cpython/setobj.py: Line 1508.
    With argument(s): '(float64, float64)':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     TypingError: All arguments must be Sets, got (float64, float64)
  raised from /home/user/python/mypython3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/cpython/setobj.py:108

During: typing of intrinsic-call at /home/user/python/popcount.py (7)

File "popcount.py", line 7:
def popcount(x): 
    <source elided>
      while(x > 0):
          x &= x - 1   
          ^
```

What is wrong with using uint64 for this?

---

The code fails with the same message even if I use:

```
print(popcount(nb.uint64(43))
```

Comment: That's a bitwise AND, not a logical AND.

Comment: It looks like you want to count the number of 1 in a binary value. If you care about performance, then you should definitively use intrinsics for that. I is not simple to do with Numba but it should be much faster. Indeed, x86-64 CPUs have an instruction for that: `popcnt`. It runs in only 1 cycles (of throughput, few cycle of latency) while your loop will take at least >10 cycles (due to the loop miss-prediction) and >20 cycles in average 0-256 integers. This means *dozens of times slower*.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I would love to but I don't think python or numba allows that.

Comment: Clearly not Python, but maybe in Numba using the [extension API](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/high-level.html#implementing-intrinsics) (one need to find the LLVM intrinsics associated to popcnt). This is quite low-level and not meant to most end-users. It would be much simpler in C/C++.

Comment: @JeromeRichard That would be great! I would love some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, I thought this was NumPy uint64 awkwardness. Turns out it's slightly different Numba uint64 awkwardness.

By NumPy dtype rules, a standard Python `int` is handled as `numpy.int_` dtype, which is signed. There's no integer dtype big enough to hold all values of both uint64 dtype and a signed dtype, so in mixed uint64/int operations, NumPy converts both operands to **float64**!

You can't use `&` with floating-point dtypes, so that's where the error would come from with NumPy type handling.

It turns out Numba uses different type handling, though. Under Numba rules, an operation on a uint64 and a signed integer produces `int64`, not `float64`. But then the assignment:

```
x &= x - 1
```

tries to assign an int64 value to a variable that initially held a uint64 value.

This is the part where Numba gets awkward. By [Numba type inference rules](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/proposals/type-inference.html),

> A *type variable* holds the type of each variable (in the Numba IR). Conceptually, it is initialized to the universal type and, as it is re-assigned, it stores a common type by unifying the new type with the existing type. The common type must be able to represent values of the new type and the existing type. Type conversion is applied as necessary and precision loss is accepted for usability reason.

Rather than converting to uint64 or keeping int64, the Numba compiler tries to unify uint64 and int64 to find a new type to use. *This* is the part where Numba accepts precision loss and converts this version of the `x` variable to float64. Then you get the error about `&` not working on float64.

Comment: Wow. That's pretty bad but thank you. C has clear rules for this which don't including converting to a float!

Comment: How come print(popcount(np.uint64(43)) also fails too then?

Comment: @Simd: Because the 1 is treated as signed. Gotta convert the 1 to uint64. (The 43 gets converted when you call the function.)

Comment: Ah so it's only the 1 that causes the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Simd As for C, AFAIR, `uin64`+`int64` binary operation can be sneaky too due to implicit promotion between signed/unsigned 64-bit values : for example `(long long)(-2) % (unsigned long long)(7)` is 0. Note that Numba uses 64-bit values on some systems but 32-bit on some others (eg. Linux vs Windows for example) so things can be even a bit more complex with implicit typing and promotions.

Answer (score 3):

To compile the code you can explicitly cast to `np.uint64()` type:

```py
import numba as nb


@nb.njit(nb.uint64(nb.uint64))
def popcount(x):
    b = 0
    while x > 0:
        x &= nb.uint64(x - 1)  # x &= x - nb.uint64(1)  works too
        b += 1
    return b


print(popcount(43))
```

Prints:

```
4
```

Comment: @Simd `x &= x - nb.uint64(1)` works too

Comment: Is there any difference in terms of the compiled code?

Comment: ...wait. Somehow this is doing the x-1 in integer math. It's not doing it in floating-point and converting back to integer - tests show no precision loss in cases where that would cause precision loss. I think there's something going on with the type inference that I don't understand - I think Numba is inferring an unsigned dtype for the 1 in the edited code.

Comment: @Simd I've did quick benchmark, and there aren't any difference between `x &= x - nb.uint64(1)` and `x &= nb.uint64(x - 1)`. And it's ~10-15x faster than pure python code.

Comment: Figured out what was going on, and fixed my answer. Turns out the float64 conversion is actually introduced when Numba's compiler processes the assignment in the original code, which is completely different from what causes the float64 conversion in regular NumPy.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm pretty sure the `nb.uint64(x - 1)` version of this code involves converting to int64 and then back to uint64, and the conversion to int64 can cause signed overflow. [Numba signed overflow is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75728233/catch-overflow-error-in-numba-integer-multiplication), so the `x - nb.uint64(1)` version is safer.