# CSAPP Datalab Myth

Tags: c

These are the codes of interest.

When I was writing the int isTmax(int x), which returns the largest two's complement integer, strange things happen. The line 7 and line 8 print out the same value 0. But clearly line 8 should print out 1 since there is a ! operator ahaed.

I am running these codes on 64-bit Windows 11 OS with gcc version 13.1.0

So my question is, why is ! operator not working here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isTmax(int x) {
   printf("Parameter,%x\n", x + 0x01);
   printf("Mask, %x\n", 1 << 31);
   printf("inside the function 1, %d\n",(x + 0x01)^(1 << 31));
   printf("inside the function 2, %d\n",!((x + 0x01)^(1 << 31)));
   return !((x + 0x01)^(1 << 31));
 }

 int main(){
     printf("Function return, %d\n", isTmax(0x7fffffff));
     printf("Outside the function,%d\n", !((2147483647 + 0x01)^(1 << 31)));
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry about misconceptions, line 7 is "inside the function 1", line 8 is "inside the function 2"

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. https://godbolt.org/z/cffqKMMv7 [Why is unsigned integer overflow defined behavior but signed integer overflow isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)

Comment: Thank u, so undefined behavior here could cause non-deterministic results across different platform?

Comment: It could cause non-deterministic results on the same platform. :-) What exactly **is** the largest possible integer plus one?

Comment: Gotcha, thank u!