# Purpose of integer literal suffix in left shift

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

In C, many operations employ bit shifting, in which an integer literal is often used. For example, consider the following code snippet:

```
#define test_bit(n, flag) (1UL << (n) & (flag))
```

As far as I know, the integer literal suffix `UL` is supposed to suppress unwanted behavior in a shift, e.g. sign-extending a signed integer may result in multiple bits being set. However, if the case is doing a left shift only, as shown above, do we still need the integer literal suffix?

As a left shift won't cause unintended behavior, I can't figure what its purpose is. Code like the above often appears in projects such as Linux kernel, which makes me think that there must be a need for it. Does anyone know the purpose of the `UL` suffix in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "integer literal", that's not a defined term in the C language.  Are you asking about why we use `1UL` instead of simply `1`?  The `UL` stands for `unsigned long` and so `1UL` is an integer expression of type `unsigned long`, whereas `1` would just be `int`.

Comment: I suppose it is a way to specify how many bits the number has, in case (n) is larger than 32.

Comment: "*As a left shift won't cause un-intended behavior*". C18 says *If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is
representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the **behavior is undefined.***

Comment: I believe "suffix" is the term you meant to use.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Re “… that's not a defined term in the C language”: No, but it should be. “Literal” is used in programming to mean something whose value is conveyed in its letters (characters). `"abc"` and `123` are literals because you know what their values are just from looking at them. That is not true of an enum member `foo`, which is also an integer constant but is not a literal. The C standard would have been to use the term “literal” for all the literal constants, instead of just string literals, and that is how OP is using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sign extending only applies to right shifts, so that's not applicable.

---

`<<` is defined as follows:

> C23 §6.5.7 ¶4 The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2E2`, wrapped around. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

There are two ways in which left-shifting values can result in undefined behaviour based on `E1`:<sup>[1]</sup>

- `E1` has a signed type and negative value.
- `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2E2` is unrepresentable.

In our case, `E1` is a positive value, so the former isn't applicable. However, the latter could apply depending on the type of `E1`.

Let's look at what results we get for different types on two systems.

- System "L" has a 32-bit `int` and a 64-bit `long` (e.g. Linux on x86-64).
- System "W" has a 32-bit `int` and a 32-bit `long` (e.g. Windows on x86-64).

| Implementation | Usage | Result on "L" | Result on "W" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1 << (n)` | `test_bit( 31, flag )` | Undefined behaviour | Undefined behaviour |
| `1L << (n)` | `test_bit( 31, flag )` | ok (since long is 64 bits) | Undefined behaviour |
| `1U << (n)` | `test_bit( 31, flag )` | ok | ok |
| `1U << (n)` | `test_bit( 63, flag )` | Incorrect result | — |
| `1L << (n)` | `test_bit( 63, flag )` | Undefined behaviour | — |
| `1UL << (n)` | `test_bit( 63, flag )` | ok | — |

So, assuming you want to be able to test any of the bits of `flag`

- `1U` is needed if `flag` can be a `signed int` or an `unsigned int` or shorter.
- `1UL` is needed if `flag` can also be a `signed long` or an `unsigned long`.

---

1. Undefined behaviour can also result based on the value of `E2`. This happens if `E2` is negative, equal to the width of `E1`, or greater than the width of `E1`. This puts a constraint on the valid values for `test_bit`'s first argument.

Comment: There's strictly speaking also a 3rd form of UB, in case E2 is negative. "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: ah, I see, I made it sound like the list I presented was exhaustive. I've addressed this.

Answer (score 12):

If your `int` is 32 bits, and you have

```
#define test_bit(n, flag) ((1 << (n)) & (flag))
```

then `test_bit(31, flag)` has undefined behavior because of the signed integer overflow.   [Why is unsigned integer overflow defined behavior but signed integer overflow isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)

Making the `1` an unsigned type avoids the UB.  Making it `unsigned long` (which is what `1UL` achieves) allows the same macro to be used for masks that are wider.  For instance, on a system where `int` is 32 bits and `long` is 64, by using `1UL` you can safely use bits up through `test_bit(63, flag)`.

Comment: This isn't an integer overflow as such, since C traditionally does not mandate one particular signedness format. It is simply UB because the left shift operator says so (C17 6.5.7) - we simply aren't allowed to shift data into the sign bit(s).

Comment: @Lundin: True, by "if int is 32 bits" I'm assuming 32 bits two's-complement or something like that.  But I think of "integer overflow is UB" as coming from 6.5p5, which also applies here, since the mathematical result of `1 << 31` (namely 2^31) is not in the range of representable values for such an `int`.

Comment: @Lundin: All three of the allowed signed-integer representations (ones or twos complement, and sign/magnitude) are unable to represent `1<<31` in a 32-bit signed integer. It's implementation-defined *which* is used, but IIRC it has to be one of the 3.  They all use the same bit-patterns as unsigned for non-negative integers, so have the same INT_MAX for the same number of value-bits.   C signed left shifts are defined in terms of arithmetic doubling, not in terms of fiddling with the bit-pattern, aren't they?

Comment: @PeterCordes In theory variables may also have padding bits (which may be trap representations). Not that I have ever seen such a system or understand how it would make sense, but the standard allows it. Might make sense for signed magnitude on some oddball ISA to place the sign bit in a byte of its own I guess.

Comment: @Lundin: Exactly, that's why I said "same `INT_MAX` for same number of *value-bits*", rather than same `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` total bits in the object-representation.  With the no-padding case being the upper bound on number of value bits in a "32-bit integer".  Only `unsigned char` and the optional fixed-width types like `int32_t` (which also guarantees 2's complement if it exists) guarantee no padding.  And yeah, IDK why you'd have padding in a primitive type like `int`

Answer (score 5):

> the integer literal "UL"

... is not called an "integer literal".  That term is not used in C language specification at all, and it risks confusion with "integer *constant*", of which the whole `1UL` would be an example.  Informally, you might call a (whole) integer constant an "integer literal", but not the "UL" part alone.  The "UL" by itself can be called a "suffix", and if we draw names from the formal grammar in the language spec then we could call it an "integer suffix" more specifically.

> IMHO, the integer literal "UL" is suppose to suppress unwanted shift, e.g. sign-extending a signed integer may result in multiple bits being set.

The primary purpose of expressing an integer constant with a suffix is to control its data type.  `1UL` has type `unsigned long int`, whereas unsuffixed `1` has type `int`.

> However, if the case is, doing logical left shift only, as shown above, do we still need the integer literal?

In a bitwise shift operation, the type of the left operand is the type of the result, and it can affect the value of the result.  It can also affect whether evaluating the expression even has defined behavior at all.

In the case of the particular macro you present, whether it is important to use `1UL` instead of just `1` depends on how the macro is used.  But there are wholly reasonable uses for which using `1UL` produces the desired effect but just `1` does not.

> As a left shift won't cause un-intended behavior,

Did you mean *undefined* behavior? A left shift of a value of a signed type (even a positive one) absolutely can have undefined behavior as far as C is concerned.  And in cases where the behavior is undefined, you are totally unjustified in assuming the result will be what you expect or intend.

> I can't figure what is its purpose then.

Even if we ignore questions around signedness, if `int` and `long int` are different size, as often they are, then `1U << n` may yield a different, well defined result than `1UL` does.  In such a case, it is unreasonable to expect `1 << n` to evaluate to the same result that `1UL << n` does, undefined behavior notwithstanding.

Comment: Re “…  is not called an "integer literal"”: Yes, it is. The C standard is not the only source of terms used in programming, and “literal” is a term for something whose value is conveyed in its letters (characters). `123` is a literal because you can see its value from its source code characters, while enum member `foo` is an integer constant but is not a literal.

Comment: If anything, the fact that C standard doesn't use the word literal (unless combined with other words) legitimizes its use since there are no conflicts.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the OP is calling the "UL" suffix itself an "integer literal".  The suffix alone absolutely is not called by that name.