# How does addition of negative integers work in C?

Tags: c, max, addition, integer-overflow, negative-integer

Given this simple code snippet:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    int8_t a = -1;
    printf("Dec: %d, Hex: %hhx\n", a, a);
    int8_t b = a + 1;
    printf("Dec: %d, Hex: %hhx\n", b, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Dec: -1, Hex: ff
Dec: 0, Hex: 0
```

which makes sense and it looks my system is using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to implement negative integers.

But `a` is an 8-bit signed integer. When adding 1 to `0xff`, it should result in an integer overflow. And according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is), signed integer overflow is *not* a defined behavior.

Thus, how does addition work for an 8-bit negative integer such that it avoids undefined behavior?

Does it have something to do with integer promotion? If so, how does it work at a low level?

**Update:** I appreciate all answers. After reading all the answers, I am still confused about promotion and wraparound. E.g., when an signed integer with the biggest data type is used, does it still do promotion and wraparound? Given this code:

```c
int main() {
    intmax_t a = -1;
    printf("Dec: %ld, Hex: %lx\n", a, a);
    intmax_t b = a + 1;
    printf("Dec: %ld, Hex: %lx\n", b, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Dec: -1, Hex: ffffffffffffffff
Dec: 0, Hex: 0
```

The result is still correct and I would like to know **why** since there is no more promotion can be done here, right?

Also, I am especially confused about the statement of "0xff + 1" versus "-1 + 1" such as:

> You're not actually adding 1 to 0xff. You're adding 1 to -1. It's just that -1 is represented as 0xff in a `int8_t`.

I am sorry, but in the computer, as far as I know, there is no idea of "-1". It's using binary representation of "-1" to do all kinds of addition, right? So, my question is that when binary representation is used to conduct addition `0xffffffffffffffff + 1`, why doesn't it overflow. What's happening under the hood?

Comment: That's not overflow. `-1` going to `0` isn't overflowing at all. (Also, despite being undefined, it does exactly what you'd expect on most architectures).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Signed overflow does *not* do what you'd expect. For example, GCC compiles `for (int i=0; i!=-1; i++) {}` as an infinite loop.

Comment: Your number is -1, not "ff".

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

> But now my question is that a is an 8-bit signed integer. When adding 1 to 0xff, it should results to an integer overflow

You're not actually adding 1 to 0xff.  You're adding 1 to -1.  It's just that -1 is *represented* as 0xff in a `int8_t`.  In a two's complement system this is effectively the same as adding the representations, but that's really an implementation detail.

Also, there is integer promotion occurring in the initialization of `b`:

```
int8_t b = a + 1;
```

Generally speaking, anytime a type smaller that `int` is used in an expression it is first *promoted* to `int`.

So the `int8_t` value of -1 whose representation is 0xff is promoted to the `int` value of -1 whose representation is 0xffffffff.  This is added to the `int` value 1 resulting in the `int` value 0.  The two's complement representation of these number effectively wraps around, but the actual result does not so it's still well defined.

Although not explicitly defined in the standard, **overflow** is when the result of an expression lies outside the range of the expression's type.  It does not necessarily mean wraparound.  The exception to this is that expressions involving unsigned operands are explicitly stated to wraparound and do not result in overflow.

Regarding your updates:

> when an signed integer with the biggest data type is used, does it still do promotion and wraparound?

There's no promotion involved when a type bigger than `int` is used, but the representation can still wrap around, and in the case of two's complement that's what it does, just like in your previous case.

> So, my question is that when binary representation is used to do addition, why doesn't it overflow?

As I mentioned before, overflow has to do with the resulting *value*, not the *representation*.

Here's another example:

```
int x = INT_MAX + 1;
```

Assuming two's complement representation and a 32-bit `int`, `INT_MAX` has a value of 2<sup>31</sup>-1 and a representation of 0x7fffffff.  Adding 1 to `INT_MAX` has a result goes outside of the range of an `int` and therefore produces overflow and triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this case there is no wraparound of the representation.  From a strictly binary standpoint, adding 1 to the representation 0x7fffffff results in 0x80000000, however that doesn't matter when the resulting value goes outside the range of an `int`.

Because overflow is undefined behavior, a compiler is allowed to assume undefined behavior does not exist and perform optimizations based on that assumption.

For example:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i!=-1; i++) {
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

GCC on optimization levels 2 and 3 will optimize this code into an infinite loop under the assumption that signed integer overflow will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion:

> The arguments of the following arithmetic operators undergo implicit conversions for the purpose of obtaining the common real type, which is the type in which the calculation is performed:
>
> - binary arithmetic *, /, %, +, -
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, both operands are integers. ***Both operands undergo integer promotions (see below)***
>
> Integer promotions
>
> Integer promotion is **the implicit conversion of a value of any integer type with rank less or equal to rank of int or of a bit-field of type _Bool(until C23)bool(since C23), int, signed int, unsigned int, to the value of type int or unsigned int.**
>
> If int can represent the entire range of values of the original type (or the range of values of the original bit-field), the value is converted to type int. Otherwise the value is converted to unsigned int.

In other words, no addition is ever performed on integer arguments smaller than `int`.

Here, in `int8_t b = a + 1;` statement:

1. `int8_t a` with value of `-1` is first signed-extended to `int` size and then signedness is changed to that of `int` (no change here). The result of the integer promotion is `(int)-1`.
2. The `int` result of addition gets truncated back to `int8_t`, in implementation-specific manner if `int8_t` cannot store the value of that `int`.

In other words, `((int)(int_8)(-1)) + 1 == (int)0`, and that is perfectly well-defined.

Comment: Ok then, how can you explain  if it was `int` instead of `int8_t`. It will simply change 0xff to `0xffff` or `0xffffffff` or `0xffffffffffffffff` depending on the length of the `int`?

Comment: @gulpr I do not understand you, post an example.

Comment: Maxim -  `-1` (assuming 32bit int) is `0xffffffff`. His problem is still unanswered. Why `0xffffffff` + 1 does not overflow? You may say - it will be promoted to `long long int` - but the story is the same, only number of `f`s changes

Comment: @gulpr `int(int_8(-1))+1` is 0. What do you not understand?

Comment: Because it is not the question.

Comment: It seems to me like gulpr understands the mechanics just fine. There is no need to be so rude. You just missed the point of the question which is about OP's confusion with 2's complement representation and overflow. Integer promotion doesn't change that.

Comment: @interjay My answer explains exactly what happens to `(int8_t)-1`, in my opinion.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin you are explaing that `-1 + 1 = 0` . I believe we all here have this knowledge and it has not to be explained. I would suggest reading OPs question once again

Comment: Your answer explains what happens, but it doesn't answer OP's question. After integer promotion, the two values have the 2's complement representation of `0x00000001` and `0xffffffff`, so the same question about why the addition doesn't count as overflow remains.

Answer (score 0):

> … it looks my system is using Two's complement to implement negative integers.

There is nothing in the output that makes it look like your C implementation uses two’s complement. The program will produce the same output regardless of whether the C implementation uses two’s complement, one’s complement, or sign-and-magnitude.

Let’s look at the first line of output, `Dec: -1, Hex: ff`, which comes from `int8_t a = -1;` and `printf("Dec: %d, Hex: %hhx\n", a, a);`. The code `int8_t a = -1;` obviously sets `a` to −1, and that is what `printf` prints for the `%d`.

For `%hhx`, you are intended to pass a `signed char` or `unsigned char`. However, these would be automatically promoted to `int`, so the argument passed to `printf`, and the parameter used by it, is always an `int`. C 2018 7.21.6.1 7 tells us “its value shall be converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing”. With `x`, it is converted to an `unsigned char`. C 2018 6.3.1.3 2 tells us how this conversion is performed:

> … the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

“One more than the maximum value that can be represented in” `unsigned char` is 256 (in your C implementation and all common C implementations). You passed −1, so it is converted to `unsigned char` by adding 256, yielding 255, which is representable in `unsigned char`. Then `printf` formatted this in hexadecimal, producing `ff`.

Observe this result does not depend on two’s complement. Given an argument of −1, `%hhx` produces `ff` because −1 + 256 = 255 = FF<sub>16</sub>. How any of these numbers are represented is irrelevant.

> When adding 1 to `0xff`, it should results to an integer overflow.

Nothing in your program adds 1 to `0xff`. −1 was displayed as `ff` by `printf` with `%hhx`, but that does not change the fact that the value of `a` is −1.

Also, adding 1 to `0xff` does not overflow. In arithmetic, operands are promoted to at least the `int` type, and adding 1 to 255 produces 256, which is representable in an `int`.

If you did have `int8_t b = 256;`, 256 would not be representable in `int8_t`. In that case, the conversion is implementation-defined, meaning the C implementation must document what the resulting value or signal would be.

> Does it have something to do with integer promotion? If so, please explain how it works in low-level.

Given an `int8_t` with value −1 in `a + 1`, the C implementation converts the `int8_t` to an `int`. It may do this by sign extension or by other means suitable for that particular C implementation. The result is −1 in an `int` type. Then −1 and 1 are added.

If two’s complement is used, −1 in a 32-bit `int` is FFFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>, and adding 1 produces all zeros with a carry out of the 32 bits, which is discarded, yielding 0.

If one’s complement is used, −1 in a 32-bit `int` is FFFFFFFE<sub>16</sub>, and adding 1 produces FFFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>, which is −0 in one’s complement, equal to +0. (It may also produce 00000000<sub>16</sub> directly, depending on implementation.)

If sign-and-magnitude is used, −1 in a 32-bit `int` is 80000001<sub>16</sub>, and adding one produces 80000000<sub>16</sub>, which is −0 in sign-and-magnitude, equal to +0. (It may also produce 00000000<sub>16</sub> directly, depending on implementation.)

In all cases, the result of adding −1 and 1 is equal to 0.

Answer (score -1):

Unsigned integers do not overflow only wrap around. When you analyze how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) numbers work under the hood - you analyze ***unsigned*** integers.

Signed integers overflow (or underflow) occurs when it gets a value larger than the maximum or minimum **signed** value which can be stored in that integer.

For `int8_t` those values are `-128` & `127`. So when you want to add or subtract `1` only `-128 - 1` or  `127 + 1` will result in overflow. `-1 + 1` does not.

How does it work under the hood?

-1 in two's complement (8 bits):

First, represent `1` in binary, then invert the bits and add one to find -1.

```
Binary representation of `+1`: `00000001`
Invert the bits: `11111110`
Add one: `11111111`
```

So, `-1` is represented as `11111111` in two's complement.

- `+1` in binary (8 bits): `00000001`
- Addition

```
       11111111  (-1 in two's complement)
     + 00000001  (+1 in binary)
       --------
      100000000  (9 bits result, but as "normal" 
      unsigned number it wraps around so we get `00000000`)
```

Comment: Any comment? I would like to know what is wrong with this answer

Comment: There is no overflow because `a + 1` is evaluated using `int`, not `int8_t`. It is then used to initialize `b`, which is an `int8_t`. For that, it is converted to `int8_t`. This conversion is implementation-defined, not an overflow. Further, two’s complement is irrelevant as the semantics of the operations in the code are defined by the C standard based on their values, not their representations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `long long int` simply more `f`s. What type is it promoted to? His question was about representation, not the standard.

Comment: Even if OP did mean to ask about representation, which is not clear, two’s complement is irrelevant. The program in the question would produce the same output whether the C implementation uses two’s complement, one’s complement, or sign-and-magnitude. The semantics are fully specified in the C standard based solely on the values involved, not the representations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil how to interpret the question is the opinion based. You interpret it this way. The question was not about the result of `-1 + 1` which is obvious of course\

Comment: This answer states “… `127 + 1` will result in overflow.” That is objectively false.