C output changed by adding a printf
int32_t result = registers[rs] + registers[rt];  
if (((registers[rs] > 0) && (registers[rt] > 0) && (result < 0)) || 
    ((registers[rs] < 0) && (registers[rt] < 0) && (result > 0))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "arithmetic overflow\n");
} else {
        registers[rd] = result;
}

Just a simple add and detect the overflow, if registers[rs] is 2147483647 and registers[rt] is 1, registers[rd] will have a result -2147483648. But if I add a printf("%d\\n", result) after declaring the variable result with same value in rs and rt, it will display arithmetic overflow
when registers[rs] is 2147483647 and registers[rt] is 1, it should output the arithmetic overflow

What you describe is typical of undefined behavior. Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. And tell us what efforts of debugging you have done.

Regarding undefined behavior, signed integer arithmetic overflow is one thing that leads to undefined behavior (or UB for short). And it happens already when calculating the value for result, after that it's too late. Once you have UB, all bets are off.

You need to test for overflow before calculating the final result ... assuming a and b are greater than 0 ==> a+b > INT_MAX ==> a > INT_MAX - b ==> if (a > INT_MAX - b) DONOTADD(); else OkToAdd();

I also find signed integer overflow UB to be annoying, this is a related thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is

This question is similar to: Detecting signed overflow in C/C++. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@SvenNilsson Indeed, this could have been made well-defined behavior in C23 when they finally tossed out exotic signedness from the language. But instead they rolled out a library to check for overflow, stdchkdint.h... which is good and all, but there's no reason this should be UB either. Because on every ISA I know, signed overflow is well-defined. C should be prepared for working on real-world computers instead of fictional computers...

Note that C23 provides the new header <stdckdint.h> with type-generic macros ckd_add(), ckd_sub() and ckd_mul().  These detect overflow (underflow) and report when it happens, permitting your code to avoid undefined behaviour from arithmetic integer overflow.  There isn't an ckd_div() because the only possible problem is exemplified by dividing INT_MIN by -1.

@Lundin: The reason for making signed integer overflow undefined behavior and for keeping it that way has more to do with optimization than with supporting esoteric computers. There are many more people who want fast code than there are people who want to use wrapping in signed arithmetic. As long as the behavior is not defined, both groups can be satisfied: Compilers can optimize, and wrapping can be supported by an implementation. If the behavior were defined, only the latter group is satisfied, since the definition would rule out the optimizations.

@EricPostpischil But then there's a pretty darn big group who don't like when computer programs are suddenly crashing. If it wasn't UB, then sanity checking with defensive programming would be possible, after which the program could gracefully handle the error instead of running off into the woods. For example the C language blocks code like this: if(a >= 0 && b >= 0) { c = a+b; do_something_else_for_10_years(); if(c < 0){ error_handler();}} Because of UB the defensive programming can be optimized away and because of that we would have to declare c as volatile which gives slower code.

@Lundin: The same analysis applies: With the behavior undefined, implementations for all users can be conforming: One implementation can optimize with the assumption overflow never occurs. Another can support wrapping. With the behavior defined, both cannot be conforming. This is one reason why “undefined behavior” should not be thought of as something you should avoid. It can be an opportunity for customization in the C implementation.

int32_t result = registers[rs] + registers[rt];  

When signed integer overflow occurs it invokes UB(Undefined Bahaviour).
You need to check before you add those integers.
bool willOverflow(int32_t a, int32_t b) 
{
    bool overflow = false;

    if (a > 0 && b > 0 && (a > INT32_MAX - b))  
    {
        overflow = true;
    }
    else if (a < 0 && b < 0 && (a < INT32_MIN - b)) 
    {
        overflow = true;
    }

    return overflow;
}

if (willOverflow(registers[rs], registers[rt]))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "arithmetic overflow\n");
} 
else 
{
    registers[rd] = registers[rs] + registers[rt];
}


Or, in C23, use the type-generic maco ckd_add() from header <stdckdint.h> to detect overflow.

@JonathanLeffler I am writing about currently supported standards. BTW do you know what the C23 GCC status is?

According to my test (code shown here), stdckdint.h is fully supported in GCC-14 and Clang-18 (but maybe also earlier versions) so they are clearly "currently supported stsndards".

@WeijunZhou I am not asking about this include.

Quite a lot of C23 is supported by GCC 14.  See Changes in GCC 14 which says "Some more C23 features have been implemented" and specifically cites <stdckdint.h>.  See also Changes in GCC 13 which lists previous changes for C23 support — things like nullptr and nullptr_t.  I expect the status for Clang is similar.

If you have a potentially overflowing signed integer operation, you need to check if it overflows before performing the operation. Otherwise, if it overflows, your program will have undefined behavior and it could do or print just about anything.
In C23, ckd_add, ckd_sub and ckd_mul was added which checks for overflow before doing the addition, subtraction or multiplication:
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdckdint.h> // chd_add, ckd_sub, ckd_mul
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    // ...

    int32_t result;
    if (ckd_add(&result, registers[rs], registers[rt])) {
        fputs("arithmetic overflow\n", stderr);
    } else {
        printf("All's well, the result is %" PRId32 "\n", result);
    }    
}

If you can't use C23, you could make your own function that checks before adding:
bool add_int32(int32_t *result, int32_t lhs, int32_t rhs) {
    // check if overflow would happen _before_ letting it happen:
    if ((rhs > 0 && INT32_MAX - rhs < lhs) ||
        (rhs < 0 && INT32_MIN - rhs > lhs))
    {
        return true; // overflow would happen
    } else {
        *result = lhs + rhs;
        return false;
    }
}

Note that the above hand-made function only handles int32_ts while the standard ckd_add is a macro using the _Generic operator to handle all integer types (other than plain char, bool and enumeration types) in any combination, as-if it was a function with the signature:
bool ckd_add(int_type1 *result, int_type2 x, int_type3 y);

