# The maximum value of "unsigned long int" in c++

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

How can I know what is the maximum assignable value for a variable from the the type of "unsigned long int"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ variable types limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966893/c-variable-types-limits)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The obvious way would be to use [`std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)

Comment: Which has value...?

Comment: @jvriesem: much of the reason it exists is because the value could vary (but it must have at least 32- bit range, so the minimum allowed value is a tad over 4 billion).

Answer (score 6):

Another way to find out would be:

```
unsigned long int i = (unsigned long int) -1;
printf("%lu\n", i);
```

Comment: doesn't work on 1's complement machines (where -0 would be the max)

Comment: @TemplateRex - `(unsigned long)-1` is always the largest value that can be represented in an `unsigned long`. Regardless of the underlying hardware, unsigned arithmetic "shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer." [basic.fundamental]/4.

Comment: @PeteBecker but e.g. `(char)-1` in 1's complement would be 254, and `(char)-0` would be 255. The problem is not the modulo arithmetic, but the mapping of signed to unsigned. What am I missing here?

Comment: That `(char)-1` is -1, and that `(char)-0` is 0. A number and its underlying representation are two different things. And `(unsigned)-1` is `(2^n)-1` by language definition.

Comment: Call me oldfashioned, but for some reason I prefer `(unsigned long)-1` to that `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()` monster... maybe, because it's so much shorter? or because it does not require one function call, two scope lookups and a template instanciation to read? or because it's plain, simple C?

Comment: @cmaster The C style expression requires exactly the detailed knowledge of the language standard that commentators above were confused about. Further, that knowledge is utterly inapplicable to signed types. When `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation, that's even more annoying. In contrast, the C++ style is self-describing and is general for all types. You could at least endorse `UINT_MAX` from `limits.h`/`climits` if you really want to avoid templates (which will be fully expanded and inlined at compile-time anyway).

Comment: @Novelocrat Yes, UINT_MAX is the best, most self describing choice :-) However, if I want a number with all its bits set, I would probably simply say `~0`, with the adequate size suffix, which does not require any arcane knowledge above knowledge of the C-operators, and is even much shorter than the cast version.

Comment: All bits set is not the same as maximum value, as the question asked.

Comment: @TemplateRex - you're looking at how underflow might be simply handled, but the standard says what it **has** to do, and if that simple implementation doesn't do it, then the implementation is wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right, but actually the relevant Standard quote is [conv.integral/2]: If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
integer (modulo 2
n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s
complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there
is no truncation). — end note ].

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: Tag is C++ isn't C.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner:And -1 in `...(unsigned long int) -1;` used for avoid `syntax error : ';'`. You can use `...(unsigned long int) -0;`.Thus `(unsigned long int) -1;` isn't Max of `unsigned int`.-O1 for your answer.

Comment: @KasiyA printf() is valid C++.

Answer (score 4):

In simple way:

```
unsigned long int i = -1;
std::cout << i;
```